# Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type

Tags: ios, socket.io, cocoapods, xcode8, ios10

I am trying to add  SocketIO swift pod file to objective c project and that swift file generates -swift.h heder file on every time i build now Error comes in heder file at this line @property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) dispatch_queue_t _Nonnull engineQueue; and error is : Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type

What i did

- Remove all pod files and reinstall
- Added pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 10.0.1’
- Removed derived data
- Clean the project
- I  got these Error in Xcode 8.3.3

  [image]

Comment: have you found any solution ?